# How to align <label> and common text with Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I'm writing a web page using Kendo UI.A part of the page looks like this

```
    <input class="k-radio" id="cwnight" type="radio" name="cw" value="night" />
    <label class="k-radio-label" for="cwnight">夜潮</label>
    <span>时间</span>
    <input id="opentime" />
```

and the JS script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#opentime").kendoDatePicker({
        //change: onChangestart,
        culture: "zh-Hans"
    });
});
```

And when I open the page in my browser, it seems like this
[image]

How could I align the word "夜潮" and the "时间" behind it？

Comment: What happens when you remove classes `k-radio` and `k-radio-label`? Aren't they aligned?

Comment: It aligned without k-radio and k-radio-label.But now "时间" seems higher

Comment: Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/.  It seems fine to me.

Comment: @Savaratkar your fiddle is empty

Comment: Oh sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/zcjzhwq1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Method 1:-**

```
<head>
    .........
    .........
    <style>
        .verticalAlignMiddle {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <input class="k-radio" id="cwnight" type="radio" name="cw" value="night" />
    <label class="k-radio-label" for="cwnight">夜潮</label>
    <span class="verticalAlignMiddle">时间</span>
    <input type="text" /> 
    .........
    .........
</body>
```

**Method 2:-**

```
<head>
    .........
    .........
    <style>
        span {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <input class="k-radio" id="cwnight" type="radio" name="cw" value="night" />
    <label class="k-radio-label" for="cwnight">夜潮</label>
    <span class="verticalAlignMiddle">时间</span>
    <input type="text" /> 
    .........
    .........
</body>
```